# upload image and display it with React and python

Tags: python, mysql, reactjs, react-native, flask

hello i want to upload image profile to my localhost(localhost/react/uploads/) folder from app and display it and, also saving the path into mysql.

so far, by using postman, i was able to save the path in mysql and send the the image to folder uploads inside the backend

my problem is that when i run the app (expo-cli) and i add the image to the profile it doesn't send the image, but  when i use postman to test the api it works, and the path of the file will be saved in mysql.  my other problem is that when i use the postman to test api it will save the path of the file but it will upload the image in the directory folder(uploads) of the app. i want a way to upload the image to the localhost server or host like loaclhost/react/uploads.

app.py

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)


class User2(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    usernm = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    email = db.Column(db.String(255))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(255))
    createdAt = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    updatedAt = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    pic_profile = db.Column(db.String(255))
    pathname = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User2 {self.usernm}>"

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()   



    @app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload():
        try:
    
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                return sennd.badRequest([], 'File tidak tersedia')
    
            file = request.files['file']
    
            if file.filename == '':
                return sennd.badRequest([], 'File tidak tersedia')
            if file and uploadconfig.allowed_file(file.filename):
                uid = uuid.uuid4()
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                renamefile = str(uuid.uuid4()) + "_" + filename
    
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], renamefile))
    
                uploads = User2(pic_profile=renamefile)
                db.session.add(uploads)
                db.session.commit()
    
                return sennd.success(
                    {
                        'pic_profile': renamefile,
                    },
                    "Sukses mengupload file"
                )
            else:
                return sennd.badRequest([], 'File tidak diizinkan')
    
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    
    
    @auth_ns.route('/signup')
    class SignUp(Resource):
        @auth_ns.expect(signup_model)
        def post(self):
            data = request.get_json()
    
            usernm = data.get('usernm')
    
            db_user = User2.query.filter_by(usernm=usernm).first()
    
            if db_user is not None:
                return jsonify({"message": f"User with username {usernm} already exists"})
    
            new_user = User2(
                public_id=str(uuid.uuid4(
                )),
                usernm=data.get('usernm'),
                email=data.get('email'),
                password=generate_password_hash(data.get('password')),
                phone=data.get('phone'),
    
    
    
    
    
            )
    
            new_user.save()
    
            return make_response(jsonify({"message": "User created successfuly"}), 201)
```

sennd.py

```
from flask import jsonify, make_response


def success(values, message):
    res = {
        'data': values,
        'message': message
    }

    return make_response(jsonify(res)), 200


def badRequest(values, message):
    res = {
        'data': values,
        'message': message
    }

    return make_response(jsonify(res)), 400
```

uploadconfig

```
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
```

signup.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { View, ScrollView, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Text from "@kaloraat/react-native-text";
import UserInput from "../components/auth/UserInput";
import SubmitButton from "../components/auth/SubmitButton";
import axios from "axios";
import CircleLogo from "../components/auth/CircleLogo";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import FontAwesome5 from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";



const Signup = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [uploadImage, setUploadImage] = useState("");
  const [usernm, setName] = useState("noura");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("noura@gmail.com");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("nooe");
  const [phone, setphone] = useState("1231");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [state, setState] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [pic_profile, setImage] = useState({ url: "", public_id: "" });


  // console.log("NAVIGATION -> ", navigation);

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (usernm!="" && password!="" && email!="" && phone!=""  ) {
     await fetch("http://127.20.10.6:5000/auth/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({usernm:usernm, password:password, email:email, phone:phone})
       }) .then(response =>response.json())
       .then(resData => {
         if(resData.message == "User created successfuly") {
         setLoading(false);
         alert(resData.message);
         navigation.navigate("Home");
         setState(data);
         // save response in async storage
          AsyncStorage.setItem("@auth", JSON.stringify(data));
         } else {
           setLoading(false);
           alert(resData.message);
         }
       })
  } else{
    alert("All fields are required");
    setLoading(false);
  }
  setLoading(false);
}

const handleUpload = async (e) => {
  let permissionResult =
    await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
  // console.log(permissionResult);
  // return;
  if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
    alert("Camera access is required");
    return;
  }
  // get image from image
  let pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    base64: true,
  });
  // console.log("PICKER RESULT => ", pickerResult);
  if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
    return;
  }
  // save to state for preview
  let base64Image = `data:image/jpg;base64,${pickerResult.base64}`;
  setUploadImage(base64Image);
  // send to backend for uploading to cloudinary

 setLoading(false);
 e.preventDefault();
    let path = await uploadFileHandler(uploadFile);
    dispatch(createItem({
       ...data,
       pic_profile: path, // idk if this is the correct property name on the data
    }, headers));

}
const uploadFileHandler = async (file) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', file);
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    const fileURL = await fetch('http://127.20.10.6:5000/upload', formData, config);
    setLoading(false);
    return fileURL.data; //this is the path of the uploaded file
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

//TODO: Submit handler
  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      contentCotainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ marginVertical: 100 }}>
      <CircleLogo>
          {pic_profile && pic_profile.url ? (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: pic_profile.url }}
              style={{
                width: 190,
                height: 190,
                borderRadius: 100,
                marginVertical: 20,
              }}
            />
          ) : uploadImage ? (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: uploadImage }}
              style={{
                width: 190,
                height: 190,
                borderRadius: 100,
                marginVertical: 20,
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleUpload()}>
              <FontAwesome5 name="camera" size={25} color="orange" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </CircleLogo>

        {pic_profile && pic_profile.url ? (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleUpload()}>
            <FontAwesome5
              name="camera"
              size={25}
              color="orange"
              style={{ maringTop: -5, marginBottom: 10, alignSelf: "center" }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        <Text title center>
          Sign Up
        </Text>

        <UserInput
          name="NAME"
          value={usernm}
          setValue={setName}
          autoCapitalize="words"
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <UserInput
          name="EMAIL"
          value={email}
          setValue={setEmail}
          autoCompleteType="email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
        />
        <UserInput
          name="PASSWORD"
          value={password}
          setValue={setPassword}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          autoComplteType="password"
        />
         <UserInput
          name="PHONE"
          value={phone}
          setValue={setphone}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          autoComplteType="phone"
        />


        <SubmitButton
          title="Sign Up"
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          loading={loading}
        />

        <Text small center>
          Already Joined?{" "}
          <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signin")} color="#ff2222">
            Sign In
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Comment: Is the problem that you can't send the image from the browser to the backend and save it or that you can't fetch the image from the backend and display it in the browser?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i can't send it to the backend